# Synchronising Offsets between two ScrollViewers without code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, scrollviewer

Right now I have two scrollviewers who both need to have the same offset at all time.

The (working) solution I have right now is with the ScrollChanged event.
If the ScrollChanged event is triggered this code is executed:

```
scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offset.X);
scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset.Y);
```

The fact is, I want to try to avoid this code-behind solution.

I think the best solution for this problem is something like this (binding):

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer_Top" HorizontalOffset="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer_Center, Path=HorizontalOffset}">...</ScrollViewer>

 <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer_Left" VerticalOffset="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer_Center, Path=VerticalOffset}" >...</ScrollViewer>

 <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer_Center" HorizontalOffset="{Binding ElementName=scrollviewer_Top, Path=HorizontalOffset}"
                                  VerticalOffset="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer_Left, Path=VerticalOffset}">...</ScrollViewer>
```

Now, when I try to build I got a few errors (HorizontalOffset/VerticalOffset cannot be set because it does not have an accesible set accessor).

Anyone knows if this is the best solution and how to handle the error? Or should I stay with the code-behind event?

Thanks

Comment: In this case, using code behind is probably the easiest solution so I'd stick to it. This is also acceptable if you're using MVVM, since this is entirely view logic.

Comment: @Adi Lester. Yes, I will stick with the code behind. Seems there is no other solution.

Comment: I just edited your title because it was previously somewhat subjective and might have led to your question being deleted by the community.

Answer (score 2):

While there is nothing wrong with using code behind in this situation, it is often customary to encapsulate event handling into Attached Properties when using WPF with MVVM. So, if you *really* wanted to get rid of the code behind, you could do this. Please refer to the [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for a detailed description of Attached Properties.

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LinkedScrollViewerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LinkedScrollViewer", typeof(ScrollViewer), typeof(ScrollViewerProperties), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnLinkedScrollViewerChanged));

public static ScrollViewer GetLinkedScrollViewer(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
{
    return (ScrollViewer)dependencyObject.GetValue(LinkedScrollViewerProperty);
}

public static void SetLinkedScrollViewer(DependencyObject dependencyObject, ScrollViewer value)
{
    dependencyObject.SetValue(LinkedScrollViewerProperty, value);
}

public static void OnLinkedScrollViewerChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)dependencyObject;
    ScrollViewer newLinkedScrollViewer = e.NewValue as ScrollViewer;
    if (newLinkedScrollViewer != null)
    {
        newLinkedScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset);
        newLinkedScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset);
    }
}
```

If this was in a class named `ScrollViewerProperties` with an Xml Namespace Prefix of `Attached`, then you could use it like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ScrollViewerToLinkWith" ... />
...
<ScrollViewer Attached:ScrollViewerProperties.LinkedScrollViewer="{Binding 
    ElementName=ScrollViewerToLinkWith}" ... />
```

Now I can't check this at the moment, so you might have to tweak it, but it looks about right. Furthermore, you can handle just about any UI event like this.